# JavaScript - function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been stuck with this for hours now. I think it's time for some new eyes on the code. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I could have certainly overlooked some detail. I should note that other functions are working properly.

I'm creating rows in a table dynamically and a few of the cells contain SELECT elements. Here is the script (just the portions where I am having trouble):

```
case 2:
    newcell.innerHTML = "<select id='size" + pid + "' class='ad_size' \
                             onChange='updateSubtotal()'> \
                             <option value='0'>Full</option> \
                             <option value='1'>Half</option> \
                             <option value='2'>Quarter</option> \
                             <option value='3'>Eighth</option> \
                             <option value='4'>Directory</option> \
                         </select>";
    break;
```

and the basic function where I am just trying to log whether or not it is being called properly:

```
function updateSubtotal() {
    console.log("size changed");
    return true;
}
```

It is probably helpful to add that I originally tried doing this with jQuery .change and it was also not working:

```
$(".ad_size").change(function(){
    console.log("size changed");
});
```

Any dumb error you can see?

Comment: change console.log to alert and see what happens - I dumped your code into a fresh page and it's happy with an alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".ad_size").live('change',function(){
           console.log("size changed");
       });
    });
```

Comment: `.on` wouldn't make any difference like that.

Comment: wow thank you. .on did not work, but .live worked like a charm.

Comment: .live should not be used with jQuery 1.7+.  You should be using .on() with the example shown in the answer by @ShankarSangoli.  Not that you should attach this to document, but you can achieve the exact same effect as .live by doing $(document).on("change", ".ad_size", function() { ... });

Answer (score 3):

Since you are adding the element dynamically try using `delegate` to attach event handler.

```
$('tableSelector').delegate('.ad_size', 'change', function(){
    console.log("size changed");
});
```

Or use `on` if you are using jQuery 1.7+

```
$('tableSelector').on('change', '.ad_size', function(){
    console.log("size changed");
});
```

Comment: .delegate (1.4+) or .on(1.7+) would be the appropriate way to do this with current versions of jQuery.